# How can I create a variable / property to pass in the same arguments to every method?

Tags: java, oop, methods, switch-statement

I'm creating a switch statement that calls different methods for each case. The caveat is, the methods all take in the exact same arguments, so I find myself duplicating code. It isn't possible to combine these methods either - as they all instantiate unique xml backing instances.

```
switch(account){

          case "25":
            getAccount25(name, address, location, accountID, business)
            break
          case "26":
            getAccount26(name, address, location, accountID, business)
            break
          case "27":
            getAccount27(name, address, location, accountID, business)
            break
          case "28":
            getAccount28(name, address, location, accountID, business)
            break
          case "29":
            getAccount29(name, address, location, accountID, business)
            break
```

Is there a way to avoid duplicating (name, address, location, accountID, business) for each method call?

Comment: Put the variables in an object or record

Comment: Why do you have those methods in the first place? Can't you use inheritance/polymorphism?

Comment: Without context (like why there's hard-coded account numbers) or much else there's little to go on. It's not clear why a `getAccount` method would require anything other than an account ID. My first instinct is there are multiple missing abstractions.

Comment: @DaveNewton - a better way to name the method would be getAccount29DetailsforAPITransfer - each account has unique details that get sent via the SOAP API call.

Comment: That doesn't help clarify anything. I'm not sure why something named `getXxx` doesn't appear to return anything, why more than an account ID is required, why there isn't a class/record for the parameter, etc. The last point answers your question--you create a parameter record like you would for anything else--but IMO there are larger concerns at play in the end.

Answer (score 0):

why don't you just go like this :

```
getAccount(account, name, address, location, accountID, business);
```

and then handle it inside your method ?

Comment: It's because I have 50 different methods for each account, and each method instantiates and maps to a completely different xml backing instance. (This is for a SOAP api call).

The result would be one massive method that handles functionality for 50 different methods.

Comment: ok that's a valid argument, you should definitely edit your question with this information

Answer (score 0):

why don't you just declare the variables (name, address, location, accountID, business) inside the class (as an instance variable) but outside the method. Then just call the methods with no entry argument.

```
switch(account){

      case "25":
        getAccount25();
        break;
      case "26":
        getAccount26();
        break;
      case "27":
        getAccount27();
        break;
      case "28":
        getAccount28();
        break;
      case "29":
        getAccount29();
        break;
}
```

The methods can use the variables as long as they are in the same class. If you are declaring the methods in another class, make the variables "public static".

Comment: Ah it's because those variables are declared outside of the switch statement - and passed through via encapsulation to multiple different methods.